# Kivy Pyinstaller SDL2.dll Load Fail

Tags: python, windows, kivy, pyinstaller

Hello I was hoping for some guidance on why my I can't get pyinstaller to work with Kivy. When I try to launch the program the CMD window comes up briefly then crashes.

I followed the steps on this tutorial https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-windows.html and I'm not sure about glew32 or sdl2 but my kv file was imported and copied to the dist\app folder.

The program will run perfectly in the python environment. I have also installed this program using pyinstaller without a kivy GUI and it worked as expected.

Below is the kivy error log which shows that sdl2 must not be importing correctly. There is a glew32.dll file and various sdl2.dll files with in the dist\app folder.

Error log

```
[INFO   ] Logger: Record log in C:\Users\mconn\.kivy\logs\kivy_17-10-
30_53.txt
[INFO   ] Kivy: v1.10.0
[INFO   ] Python: v2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:19:22) [MSC 
v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] Factory: 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] Image: Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, 
img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] Text: Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] OSC: using <thread> for socket
[INFO   ] Window: Provider: sdl2
[CRITICAL] Window: Unable to find any valuable Window provider.
sdl2 - ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be 
found.
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-packages\kivy\core\__init__.py", 
  line 67, in core_select_lib
    cls = cls()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-
  packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 140, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-
  packages\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line 899, in __init__
    self.create_window()
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\site-
  packages\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", line 269, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)
  File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 110, in 
  kivy.core.window._window_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window 
  (kivy\core/window\_window_sdl2.c:2436)
  File "kivy\graphics\cgl.pyx", line 52, in 
  kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name (kivy\graphics\cgl.c:3044)
  File "kivy\graphics\cgl.pyx", line 60, in 
  kivy.graphics.cgl.cgl_get_backend_name (kivy\graphics\cgl.c:2879)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.5\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in 
  import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "c:\users\mconn\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-
  wy26bb\pyinstaller\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 687, in 
  load_module

  [CRITICAL] App: Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

**.spec code**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
from kivy.deps import sdl2, glew

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['C:\\Users\\mconn\\Desktop\\Python Course\\Crash Locator\\Python Program\\FARS_crash_summary.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\mconn\\Desktop\\Python Course\\Crash Locator\\Program'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='CrashLocator',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe, Tree('C:\\Users\\mconn\\Desktop\\Python Course\\Crash Locator\\Python Program\\'),
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               *[Tree(p) for p in (sdl2.dep_bins + glew.dep_bins)],
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='CrashLocator')
```